# Approximating using Taylor series expansion

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

Using linearisation (truncated Taylor series expansion) around 0, show that:

$1-2 \omega \sin ^{2}\left(\frac{k \pi h}{2}\right)$ $\approx$ $1-\frac{\omega k^{2} \pi^{2}}{2} h^{2}$

I am a bit lost on how to go about this. I am not sure what I am suppose to be taking the derivative with respect to as well.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: To start with, do you know the Taylor expansion of $\sin x$?

Comment: Hint: notice that the given equation is equivalent to $\sin\frac{k\pi h}2\approx\frac{k\pi h}2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the quadratic Taylor polynomial of the cosine, we obtain
$$
2\sin ^2 \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right) = 1 - \cos x \approx \frac{{x^2 }}{2}
$$
for $x$ near $0$. Thus with $x=k\pi h$,
$$
1 - 2\omega \sin ^2 \left( {\frac{{k\pi h}}{2}} \right) \approx 1 - \omega \frac{{(k\pi h)^2 }}{2} = 1 - \frac{{\omega k^2 \pi ^2 }}{2}h^2 
$$
for $h$ near $0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Start with
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^5\right)$$
$$\sin^2(x)=x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
Make $x=\frac {k \pi}2h$